# Is any way to make debugger step into a method which is defined by a macro?

Tags: c++, debugging, macros

a 3rdparty class has many methods defined like this?

```
  ///@{
  /**
   * Set/Get the brightness of the light (from one to zero).
   */
  vtkSetMacro(Intensity, double);
  vtkGetMacro(Intensity, double);
  ///@}

  ///@{
  /**
   * Turn the light on or off.
   */
  vtkSetMacro(Switch, vtkTypeBool);
  vtkGetMacro(Switch, vtkTypeBool);
```

And the debugger of Eclpse CDT won't step into these kinds of methods at all,any way to make debugger step into them?

---------update add macro define---

```
//
// Set built-in type.  Creates member Set"name"() (e.g., SetVisibility());
//
#define vtkSetMacro(name, type)                                                                    \
  virtual void Set##name(type _arg)                                                                \
  {                                                                                                \
    vtkDebugMacro(<< this->GetClassName() << " (" << this << "): setting " #name " to " << _arg);  \
    if (this->name != _arg)                                                                        \
    {                                                                                              \
      this->name = _arg;                                                                           \
      this->Modified();                                                                            \
    }                                                                                              \
  }
```

Comment: Into what? It's a macro, there's no "code" per-se. They exist only where the macro is expanded.

Comment: Macros are expanded into a single line. Stepping in a debugger is line-based. If you have multiple statements on a single line, then the debugger will step over them all.

Comment: If within the macros there are function calls involved you might `step into` instead to see at least parts of...

Comment: The library should have the macroses defined somewhere. If you find the definitions and it doesn't help you with your debugging, please share the definitions here, and explain what exactly is not clear with it?

Comment: If you don't have symbols and code for the library whose methods you want to step into, then you'll only be able to step into the disassembly at best. I don't know if Eclipse specifically supports this, but Visual Studio does.

Comment: @tadman Is there any way to expand it first then compile expanded code?

Comment: @AlexLuya that's exactly what happens.  Macros get expanded as a pre-processor step in the compilation process.  The "real" compiler only gets to see the code after the macro expansion/replacement has taken place.  "_...The preprocessor is executed at translation phase 4, before the compilation. The result of preprocessing is a single file which is then passed to the actual compiler...."_ [Preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor) . TL;DR macros don't exist they work similar to search/replace in the editor.

Comment: You could do it manually, like just substitute it yourself, but there's not a ton of code here that can go wrong. As others pointed out, "step into" will still work.